# Where does the output of System.out.println go in gradle test?

Tags: gradle

Where does the output of System.out.println go in gradle test?

I have a sample test defined as follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    public class LibraryTest {
        @Test public void NaiveScenarioTest() {
          System.out.println("java sample scenario started");
          SampleScenario s = new SampleScenario("sample");
        }
    }
```

Running `gradle test`, I get all the success indicators, but the stdout output of the println doesn't show in the terminal nor in gradle's html report. Whereas this is desired only for a quick debug scenario, I still would be happier to have stdout redirected somewhere visible, preferably showing in the terminal as I `gradle test`.

What is the simplest or best advice?

Answer (score 54):

The test output is part of the standard html report located in `build/reports/tests/test/index.html`. Simply click through the report to find the specific test you are interested in and there is a tab with Standard Output (and Standard Error if applicable).

To show the outputs during the `gradle test` run, you can modify your test task:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

You can customize the output even more, [see the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html).

Comment: Wow I have looked at the reports so many times and never seen that tab. Just goes to show you - users don't read

Comment: Also, when running gradle use -I option as well as showStandardStreams in build file.

Comment: I tried `gradle test -l` and it complained about the option. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `gradle test -i` (John means `i` not `l`)